# how to call view with specific record using button?

Tags: python, odoo

I need help calling a list view to show specific record using a button.

Currently I am using the following code:

```
<button name="%(action_menu_activitydata)d" type='action'/>


<record id="action_menu_activitydata" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">ActivityData</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">budget.activitydata</field>            
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="activitydata"/>
    </record>
```

When I click on the button I can see all the records in the list view. How can I open the the form view with a specific record?

Answer (score 0):

For that use object instead of action

Check this example ths may help you

Use your module tree view, form view, then resource id you need to view (optional)

```
def redirect_phonecall_view(self, cr, uid, phonecall_id, context=None):
    model_data = self.pool.get('ir.model.data')
    # Select the view
    tree_view = model_data.get_object_reference(cr, uid, 'crm', 'crm_case_phone_tree_view')
    form_view = model_data.get_object_reference(cr, uid, 'crm', 'crm_case_phone_form_view')
    search_view = model_data.get_object_reference(cr, uid, 'crm', 'view_crm_case_phonecalls_filter')
    value = {
            'name': _('Phone Call'),
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'tree,form',
            'res_model': 'crm.phonecall',
            'res_id' : int(phonecall_id),
            'views': [(form_view and form_view[1] or False, 'form'), (tree_view and tree_view[1] or False, 'tree'), (False, 'calendar')],
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'search_view_id': search_view and search_view[1] or False,
    }
    return value
```

Comment: how to pass the "phonecall_id" to the function in button ?
    <button name="redirect_phonecall_view(phonecall_id)" type='object'/> ..

Can i pass it this way ?

Comment: no you have to use type="object" instead of action in xml and need to use function like this in py file